# Navigating through forms AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have two different HTML forms

1. index.html
2. home.html

I am trying to create a login in index.html and if it is authenticated i want to navigate to home.html and if its not i am displaying an alert message. But the page does not navigate. Any ideas as to what i am doing wrong?

My code is as follows

**index.html**

```
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-view></div>
<form ng-submit="login(username, password)">
      <label>User name</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="username" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" ng-model="password" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
      <br/>  

      <br/><br/>
      <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="">Submit</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</form>

</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config([ '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/home', {
            templateUrl : 'home.html',
            controller : 'HomeController'
        }).
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'index.html',
            controller : 'myCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
               redirectTo: 'home.html'
            });
       //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true); //Remove the '#' from URL.
    }
]);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$location) {
    // $scope.count = '';
    $scope.login = function(username, password) {
        if (username == 'admin' && password == '1234')
         { 
         $location.path("/home" );
         }
        else
        {
         alert('invalid username and password');
        } 
    }
});
</script>

</body>
```

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="HomeConroller">

<button ng-click="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>

<p>{{ count }}</p>

</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('HomeConroller', function($scope) {
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.myFunction = function() {
        $scope.count++;
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try `$state.go("/home");`. Make sure you inject `$state` into the controller

Comment: @theblindprophet there is no `$state` in ngRoute

Comment: Should be seeing error in console for typo of controller name

Comment: How to check for errors in console?

Comment: You should only have one page ...and the templates only include the html needed for content. Suggest you study tutorial for how routing works

Comment: Hit F12 .....................

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
window.location.href = "home.html";
```

Instead of

```
$location.path("/home" );
```

Comment: Still no avail!!! Infact when i dont authenticate also it does not display the alert!! Any thoughts??

Comment: `home.html` is a template. This isn't how angular routing works

Comment: @charlietfl wat do i need to do?